# Fractional Sobolev embedding theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde

Let $\psi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^N)$ be a test function with support iN $B(0,R)$. Is it true that the following inequality holds
$$\int_{B(0,R)} \psi^2 u^{\frac{4}{1+\beta}} dx \le R^{1+\beta} \int_{B(0,R)} \psi^2 \left(\int_{\mathbb R^N}  \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{N+2\alpha}} dy \right) dx$$
for at least some values of $1 \le N \le 3$, $\beta \in (0,1)$, $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

Comment: For *all* test functions $\psi$? That would simply mean that $u^{4/(1+\beta)}(x) \leqslant R^{1+\beta} \int |u(x)-u(y)|^2/|x-y|^{N+2\alpha}dy$ for all $x \in B(0,R)$, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Is there a variation of this inequality which is true?

Comment: No idea. I would start by looking at the local case: when $\int_{B(0,R)} \psi^2 u^p \leqslant R^q \int_{B(0,R)} \psi^2 |\nabla u|^2$? This looks a bit like the Poincaré inequality, but not quite. Also, both sides scale differently if $u$ is replaced by $\lambda u$.